# Efficient recurrent network for sequences of varying length

Tags: neural-network, rnn

Suppose I have a bunch of sequences of varying lenghts. The absolute majority of them are short, just a few dozens items long. However, very few of them are significantly longer - more than a hundred items long. The question is, how to organize them efficiently as an input to recurrent layer?

Padding doesn't work, since many sequences need to be heavily padded. Limiting batch size is not an option - these sequences are obtained as parts of a larger structure.

Comment: Could you please tell us more about the problem, you're trying to solve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Sequence bucketing**

Depending on the input length of sequences you can dynamically change the padding and speed it up.

Take a look at here [Sequence bucketing](https://www.kaggle.com/bminixhofer/speed-up-your-rnn-with-sequence-bucketing)

Comment: I had a glance. It seems like breaking data into smaller batches, long going with long and short going with short, correct?

Comment: There are different techniques to solve this, at the end of the day, optimisation problem. What you said is one way, that could be expensive (depending on the data) You can also use arbitrary batches and depending on the size of the longest in every batch padd accordingly.  Have a look at here https://medium.com/@rashmi.margani/how-to-speed-up-the-training-of-the-sequence-model-using-bucketing-techniques-9e302b0fd976